# When to use Vert.x cluster

Tags: module, cluster-computing, vert.x

I have a java (gradle) project with multiple modules. All of the modules run on the same server but I want them to be independent, i.e. module A should be started and stopped no matter if module B is running or stopped and vice versa.
Each module is a vert.x verticle and the modules should be able to communicate with each other.
I read that if the verticles run on the same machine, it's not a good practice to create a clustered vertx instance, but if I don't cluster them, then I got different instances and therefore different eventbusses.

What would you recommend?

(1) Cluster the verticles on the same machine

(2) let the verticles communicate via a router (is this a bad practice?)

(3) Restructure the project in some way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [deploy verticles](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#deployVerticle-java.lang.String-) to get a deployment id and also [undeploy them](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#undeploy-java.lang.String-) using the same id. That means they are already independent.

The simplest way would be to have them running in the same process communicating via the event bus.

Options 1 & 2 that you listed would introduce unnecessary latency and make your application perform worse.

Comment: In this way, I cannot start the verticles via `gradle vertxRun`and especially start and kill the gradle process and therefore the verticle whenever I want right? Or how do I tell my master verticle (which deployed the other ones) to start and stop verticles in a not programmatical way?

Comment: The way you want to add this is completely up to you. You could simply integrate the [vert.x shell](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-shell/java/#_base_commands) or have your main verticle listen to start and stop commands via http or any other way that you like.

Comment: Ah, i didn't know vertx. shell, thank you!